# How to access folder image path in asp.net core 2.2 web application

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a solution UI project and another web api solution project.In web api I have a image folder.I want to get that path in UI project.

public IActionResult Index()
        {

```
        string imgUrl = "F:\\NARESHPANDIT\\IDENTICA-TFS\\Minha Pousada\\Management micro-service\\Minha-Pousada.WebApi\\wwwroot\\BProfileFile";

        BusinessProfileModel model = new BusinessProfileModel();
        string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        List<BusinessProfileModel> businesslist = new List<BusinessProfileModel>();
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = objAPI.CallAPI("/BusinessProfile/GetBusinessProfile", contents))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString))
                {
                    businesslist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BusinessProfileModel>>(responseString);
                }
            }
        }
        model.Imgurl = imgUrl;
        model.BusinessProfileList = businesslist;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: there are few things you need to take care: 1. why you serialize empty model? 2. why you pass serialize model into Call Api without ref?  3. If your CallAPI will return Path, then you already fix issue, please tell us what are you really want to do.

Comment: I have Web Api project in one Solution and I have Another UI Project In another solution.Both project is Different and both Solution is different.I have a Image folder in  Web Api project .I want to show image in UI Project.But I don't understand how to get image folder path.So I can Show image on browser.

Comment: Okay, you can build a API call in webAPI project and return base64 data for image, do not try to return image path, you can search how to convert image to base64 and how to show image in UI with base64.

Comment: I also try ,but no success.

Comment: which part not success? Convert to base64? Call Api failed? or with base64 but can't display?

Comment: I want to show simplly show image.
Like this:
<img src="@Model.Imgurl\@item.Logo" style="height:100px;width:100px;" />

Comment: i have already convert image to base64 in wep api.

Comment: But I want to show only image in gridview .
I use this code:
<img src="@Model.Imgurl\@item.Logo" style="height:100px;width:100px;" />
Here @Model.Imgurl is F:\\NARESHPANDIT\\IDENTICA-TFS\\Minha Pousada\\Management micro-service\\Minha-Pousada.WebApi\\wwwroot\\BProfileFile
But not working image is broken.

Comment: here you have few problem, @Model.ImgUrl\@Item.Logo is invalid, if you want to use image path, you need to combine it with this @(Model.ImgUrl +"\\"+Item.Logo), for base64, u can use this 
$image = 'http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png';
// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;

Comment: @(Model.ImgUrl +"\\"+Item.Logo) and @Model.ImgUrl\@Item.Logo both are equal output.